# extremely strange logistic regression results

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I am very new to r and statistics so excuse me if the answer to my question is very obvious. I have surveyed 64 people on their Facebook behaviour related to their political participation. One of my independent variables is how many Facebook friends the people have and i divided their answers into 3 categories: 0-500= 1, 500-1000= 2 and 1000+ = 3.The independent variable is whether or not they voted, coded 0= no and 1= yes. I have been trying to run this as a logistic regression but for some reason it is not working.
This is my code:

```
#fit bivariate logistic regression model for amount of friends and voting
fit3 <-glm(vote~as.factor(friends), family=binomial(link="logit"), data=politicalparticipation)
summary(fit3)
exp(coef(fit3))
abs(1-exp(coef(fit3)))*100
sjt.glm(fit3)
```

However, i continuously get the error message that there is a warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

If someone could help me out, that'd be great!

Comment: Try calculating the fraction of yes and no answers for each of the three categories.  If one or more categories has 100% yes or 100% no answers, that's the source of the trouble; it's referred to as "separation" in the literature.

Comment: You are looking at perfect separation, for at least one level of facebook friends people will always vote or never vote

Comment: You may find it better to use number of friends (possibly transformed) as a predictor rather than categorise it which inevitably leads to a mis-specified model even if you do not have separation

Comment: You need 96 observations just to have any hope in estimating a SINGLE probability.

Comment: @jbowman how exactly can i do that in r ?

Comment: Use the "table" function is probably the easiest; `table(df$vote, df$friends)` where `df` is the name of your data frame.